# RxJava: How to get all results AND errors from an Observable

Tags: java, multithreading, rx-java, reactive-programming, observable

I'm working on a project that involves Hystrix, and I decided to use RxJava.  Now, forget Hystrix for the rest of this because I believe the main problem is with my complete screwing up of writing the Observable code correctly.

**Need:**
I need a way to return an observable that represents a number of observables, each running a user task.  I want that Observable to be able to return all results from the tasks, even errors.

**Problem:**
Observable streams die on errors.  If I have three tasks and the second task throws an exception, I never receive the third task even if it would have succeeded.

**My Code:**

```
public <T> Observable<T> observeManagedAsync(String groupName,List<EspTask<T>> tasks) {
    return Observable
            .from(tasks)
            .flatMap(task -> {
                try {
                    return new MyCommand(task.getTaskId(),groupName,task).toObservable().subscribeOn(this.schedulerFactory.get(groupName));
                } catch(Exception ex) {
                    return Observable.error(ex);
                }
            });
}
```

Given that MyCommand is a class that extends HystrixObservableCommand, it returns an Observable and so shouldn't figure in on the problems I'm seeing.

**Attempt 1:**

Used `Observable.flatMap` as above

- *Good:* Each Command is scheduled on it's own thread and the tasks run asynchronously.
- *Bad:* On first Command exception, Observable completes having emitted previous successful results and emitting the Exception.  Any in-flight Commands are ignored.

**Attempt 2:**

Used `Observable.concatMapDelayError` instead of `flatMap`

- *Bad:* For some reason, tasks run synchronously.  Why??
- *Good:* I get all the successful results.
- *~Good:* OnError gets a Composite exception with a list of the exceptions thrown.

Any help will be greatly appreciated and probably result in me being very embarrassed for not having thought of it myself.

**Additional Code**

This test succeeds with `Observable.flatMap`, but fails when using `Observable.concatMapDelayError` because the tasks do not run asynchronously:

*java.lang.AssertionError: Execution time ran over the 350ms limit: 608*

```
@Test
public void shouldRunManagedAsyncTasksConcurrently() throws Exception {
    Observable<String> testObserver = executor.observeManagedAsync("asyncThreadPool",getTimedTasks()); 
    TestSubscriber<String> testSubscriber = new TestSubscriber<>();
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    testObserver.doOnError(throwable -> {
        System.out.println("error: " + throwable.getMessage());
    }).subscribe(testSubscriber);
    System.out.println("Test execution time: "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime));
    testSubscriber.awaitTerminalEvent();
    long execTime = (System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime);
    System.out.println("Test execution time: "+execTime);
    testSubscriber.assertCompleted();
    System.out.println("Errors: "+testSubscriber.getOnErrorEvents());
    System.out.println("Results: "+testSubscriber.getOnNextEvents());
    testSubscriber.assertNoErrors();
    assertTrue("Execution time ran under the 300ms limit: "+execTime,execTime>=300);
    assertTrue("Execution time ran over the 350ms limit: "+execTime,execTime<=350);
    testSubscriber.assertValueCount(3);
    assertThat(testSubscriber.getOnNextEvents(),containsInAnyOrder("hello","wait","world"));
    verify(this.mockSchedulerFactory, times(3)).get("asyncThreadPool");
}
```

Tasks for the above unit test:

```
protected List<EspTask<String>> getTimedTasks() {
    EspTask longTask = new EspTask("helloTask") {
        @Override
        public Object doCall() throws Exception {
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(100);
            return "hello";
        }
    };
    EspTask longerTask = new EspTask("waitTask") {
        @Override
        public Object doCall() throws Exception {
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(150);
            return "wait";
        }

    };
    EspTask longestTask = new EspTask("worldTask") {
        @Override
        public Object doCall() throws Exception {
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(300);
            return "world";
        }
    };
    return Arrays.asList(longTask, longerTask, longestTask);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Observable.onErrorReturn()`, and return special value (e.g. null), then filter non-special values downstream. Keep in mind that source observable will complete on error. Also depending on use case `Observable.onErrorResumeNext()`methods can be useful aswell. If you are interested in error notifications, use `Observable.materialize()`, this will convert items and `onError()`, `onComplete()` into Notifications, which then can be filtered by `Notification.getKind()`

**Edit**.
All operators mentioned above should be added right after `.toObservable().subscribeOn(this.schedulerFactory.get(groupName));` assuming try/catch was absent.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `mergeDelayError`:

```
public <T> Observable<T> observeManagedAsync(String groupName,List<EspTask<T>> tasks) {
    return Observable.mergeDelayError(Observable
        .from(tasks)
        .map(task -> {
            try {
                return new MyCommand(task.getTaskId(),groupName,task).toObservable().subscribeOn(this.schedulerFactory.get(groupName));
            } catch(Exception ex) {
                return Observable.error(ex);
            }
        }));
}
```

Note that your MyCommand constructor should not throw any exceptions; this allows your code to be written more concisely:

```
public <T> Observable<T> observeManagedAsync(String groupName,List<EspTask<T>> tasks) {
    return from(tasks)
           .map(task -> new MyCommand(task.getTaskId(), groupName, task)
                        .toObservable()
                        .subscribeOn(this.schedulerFactory.get(groupName)))
           .compose(Observable::mergeDelayError);
```

}

Keep in mind that this will still invoke `onError` at most once; if you need explicit handling of all errors, use something like an `Either<CommandResult, Throwable>` as the return type (or handle the errors and return an empty observable).

Answer (score 1):

Use `.materialize()` to allow all emissions and errors to come through as wrapped notifications then deal with them as you wish:

```
     .flatMap(task -> {
            try {
                return new MyCommand(task.getTaskId(),groupName,task)
                    .toObservable()
                    .subscribeOn(this.schedulerFactory.get(groupName))
                    .materialize();
            } catch(Exception ex) {
                return Observable.error(ex).materialize();
            }
        });
```